# MySQL DELETE does not work

Tags: mysql

DELETE FROM Sport WHERE SportId=1;

When I execute above, I get this error. Please help me;

DogSport is in use.Error: DELETE FROM Sport WHERE SportId=1
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dogsport`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`EqId`) REFERENCES `equipment` (`EqId`))

```
/* Creating Sport table */
CREATE TABLE Sport(
SportId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
SportName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Description VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(SportId)
);

/* Inserting values for Sport table */
INSERT INTO Sport(SportName,Description)
VALUES('Agility','This is a fun dog sport which a handler directs a dog through a course of obstacles. Body motion, speed, hand signals are used by the handler to direct the dog.'),
('Flyball','Energetic and exciting sport which is also called drag racing for dogs'),
('Disc Dog','This sport is also known as Frisbee dog. The sport involves the bond between the owner and dog, by letting them to work together'),
('Dog Diving','This sport involves loving run, jumping, and swimming. This is a very popular sport nowadays'),
('Cani-Cross','This is a sport event which running off-road with dogs. It is an useful sport which keeps the owner and the dog fit by a physical workout and directional commands.');

/* Creating UserSport table */
CREATE TABLE UserSport(
UserId INT NOT NULL,
SportId INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(UserId,SportId),
FOREIGN KEY(UserId) REFERENCES User(UserId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(SportId) REFERENCES Sport(SportId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

/* Inserting values for UserSport table */
INSERT INTO UserSport(UserId,SportId)
VALUES(1,2),
(1,4),
(1,3),
(1,5);

/* Creating Equipment table */
CREATE TABLE Equipment(
EqId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
EqName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
Price DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
SportId INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(EqId),
FOREIGN KEY(SportId) REFERENCES Sport(SportId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

/* Inserting values for Equipment table */
INSERT INTO Equipment(EqName,Price,SportId)
VALUES('Wing Jump',6700,1),
('Tire',4500,1),
('Open Tunnel',9000,1),
('Chute',3000,1),
('Boomerang Flyball Box',6300,2),
('Training Box',4200,2),
('Flyball Jumps',7800,2),
('Can Am Flyball Box',3100,2),
('Flyball Harness',1800,2),
('Balance Disc',2000,3),
('Training Punches',1000,3),
('Retrieve Water Ring',4500,4),
('Dive Jacket',3000,4),
('Aqua Floating Toy',1500,4),
('Cani-Cross Harness',4000,5),
('PawZ Dog Boots',1000,5),
('Custom Shoulder Harness',3000,5);


/* Creating User table */
CREATE TABLE User(
UserId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Title VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
FName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
LName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Phone VARCHAR(15),
Address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
Password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY(UserId)
);

/* Inserting values for User table */
INSERT INTO User(Title,FName,LName,Email,Phone,Address,Password)
VALUES('Mr.','Raveen','Chandra','admin@dogsport.com','0778547079','Ambalangoda','123'),
('Miss','Bisma','Ishani','bisma@gmail.com','0785234123','Colombo','456'),
('Dr','Shantha','Kumara','shantha@yahoo.com','0912374392','Ambalangoda','789'),
('Ms.','Madusha','Perera','perera@yahoo.com','0782361490','Galle','3235');
```

Comment: you are missing a table which is child table of equipment....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be at least one child table of equipment, you are missing which.

First execute below command which will provide you all child tables of equipment table-

```
select * from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where TABLE_SCHEMA ='your_db' and REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME ='equipment';
```

Note: change your_db with your db name.

Then either delete rows from its child table or there also should be "on delete cascade" instead of "on delete cascade no action"

There is short way also which is not a clean way-

You can disable your foreign key checks and delete, but I will not suggest it.

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
DELETE FROM Sport WHERE SportId=1;
set foreign_key_checks=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

First delete on the other tables that has `FK` to this table , and only then delete from it:

```
DELETE FROM Equipment WHERE SportId=1;
DELETE FROM UserSport  WHERE SportId=1;
DELETE FROM Sport WHERE SportId=1;
```

Comment: Sir, you are correct. But sir I have used ON DELETE CASCADE. Why does not that work?